# Realm file format version (22) crashes iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

With the latest updates to Realm by now on 10.39.1 and RealmDatabase 13.10.1, iOS app in Xcode (14.3) crashes with the below error, but Realm Studio 14 shoots error that "Database upgrade required but prohibited". Realm Studio 12 still provides access to data. Any clues?

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=6 "Realm file at path '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A556AEF9-5D0B-4B81-91D9-61045A03BA80/AppName.app/data.realm' cannot be opened in read-only mode because it has a file format version (22) which requires an upgrade" UserInfo={Error Code=6, NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A556AEF9-5D0B-4B81-91D9-61045A03BA80/AppName.app/data.realm, Error Name=FileFormatUpgradeRequired, NSLocalizedDescription=Realm file at path '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A556AEF9-5D0B-4B81-91D9-61045A03BA80/AppName.app/data.realm'
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this.

At the moment, you'll need to use Realm Studio 14.0.2, which supports 10.38 and above. As mentioned, current release is 10.39.1.

Here's what I did (Specific steps for reference):

1. Quit XCode completely, quit Realm Studio

   Get the latest Realm Studio from the [Realm Studio Download](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases)
2. Ensure podfile includes this line

   pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
3. delete podfile.lock from project folder
4. at command line ensure latest cocoapods is installed

   sudo gem install cocoapods
5. at command line

   pod repo update
6. at command line

   pod install

note, the command line should show

```
Installing Realm 10.39.1 (was 10.38.0)
Installing RealmSwift 10.39.1(was 10.38.0)
```

7. Open project using the .xcworkspace, clean and *run project*

at this point the realm will be updated and can be opened with the project along with Realm Studio

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I use Xcode packages instead of pods and updated to the latest 10.39.1 and 10.39.1 respectively. Maybe the difference is related to the step 2 in your advice.

Comment: @ArtisUniverse You could build a test project using CocoaPods (per the above steps) and see if it makes any difference. It only take a few minutes and that would provide a bit more info.